# O que significa a barra "/" no border-radius?

Tags: css

No CSS, temos o atributo `border-radius`.

Geralmente o uso das seguintes formas:

```
border-radius:10px;

border-radius:10px 20px 20px 10px;
```

Porém me deparei com o seguinte código um dias desses e até hoje estou sem entender pra que ele serve na prática.

```css
 div {
   border-radius: 100px/55px;
   background-color:#333;
   height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

O que significa essa barra no valor de `border-radius`?

Comment: Mas isso deforma as formas de maneira totalmente diferente.  Então como ele funciona?

Comment: @AndréBaill, mas ele não gera bordas iguais para os quatro lados, certo?

Comment: Deram +1 seu comentário, mas não parece ser isso @AndréBaill. Eu imaginei que não fosse mesmo, porque os lados não ficam iguais. Veja meu exemplo com snippet na pergunta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A barra serve para especificar dois raios diferentes para a curvatura.

```
border-radius: 40px / 20px;
   horizontal --^      ^-- vertical
```

[image: representacao visual]

A mesma sintaxe pode ser usada para especificar os quatro cantos.

Note a diferença para o Chrome:

```css
#element {
  border-radius: 80px 70px 60px 50px / 30px 20px 10px 5px;

  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
</div>
```

Isto evita ter que escrever tudo separado:

```css
#element {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 80px 30px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 70px 20px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px 5px;

  border-top-left-radius: 80px 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 70px 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px 5px;

  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
</div>
```

A [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius) documenta bem estas propriedades. A imagem do topo da resposta veio do SitePoint, que tem [um artigo](http://www.sitepoint.com/setting-css3-border-radius-with-slash-syntax/) falando à respeito.

Comment: Então não tem nada a ver com a "divisão" que me responderam nos comentários?

Comment: Nadinha. É horizontal e vertical

Comment: +1. Obrigado por ter uma resposta sobre isso em português ;)

Comment: Testado no IE11 e no Opera (chromium). Agradeço observações de usuários de outros browsers.

Answer (score 4):

O sinal de "/" no border-radius funciona da seguinte maneira:
declara os valores do eixo horizontal em sentido horário, e depois os valores do eixo vertical, também separados por uma barra:

border-radius: 10px 20px 5px 20px / 5px 5px 20px 10px;

Nesse exemplo ficaria assim:

```css
#border{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#000;
 border-radius: 10px 20px 5px 20px / 5px 5px 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
  </div>
```

É possivel também, usar as propriedades:

```
border-radius-topleft
border-radius-topright
border-radius-bottomright
border-radius-bottomleft
```

Que são auto explicativas, definem bordas em locais específicas da div ou seja lá o que você esteja estilizando.

Este site traz [um artigo](http://www.infowester.com/css3bordas.php) interessante sobre bordas.

Comment: +1. Não sabia que dava pra usar `/` com múltiplos atributos

Comment: Tem mais uma forma de fazer isso, vou editar a minha resposta.

Comment: Editei minha resposta com mais informações sobre border.