# CSS: Border Radius

Tags: css, html5

Estou fazendo um projeto onde estou usando o `border radius` para fazer um menu vertical.
Gostaria que o Menu ficasse com a border radius reta, desta forma arredondada :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E atualmente está ficando desta forma:

```css
.teste{
 height:12%;
 width:65%;
 background-color: rgb(56, 66, 65);
 opacity:0.5;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:30%;
    border: 2px solid red;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 250px 170px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Menu Vertical</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="teste" class="teste"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como faço para ficar reta?

Comment: Bom dia! encontrei esse site aqui, ja da pra tirar uma ideia: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

Comment: E a parte de cima, como é?

Comment: Atualmente estou tentando fazer somente a div como a forma da imagem, ao invés de ficar meio arredondada, ficar ponte-aguda (como uma espada)

Comment: Dê uma olhada nisso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109200/criar-bot%C3%A3o-com-borda-octagonal-usando-somente-html-e-css

Comment: @Sora eu estou tentando aplicar o princípio dessa pergunta na sua resposta: [O que significa / no border-radius](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101324/o-que-significa-a-barra-no-border-radius)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer botão Inclinado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56819/3635) e [Criação de div diagonal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238393/3635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é com `border-radius`, pois *radius = raio*, ou seja essa propriedade cria um raio de curvatura nos vértices da `div` por isso fica arredondado.

Mas com um `pseudo-elemento` e skewX() vc consegue.

```css
.teste{
 height:12%;
 width:65%;
 background-color: rgb(56, 66, 65);
    color:#ddd;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:30%;
    padding-left: 50px; /* mesma largura que o elemento after */
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.teste::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(56, 66, 65);
    top: 0px;
    left: -25px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    transform: skewX(25deg);
}
```

```html
    <div id="teste" class="teste"></div>
```

Comment: Vou estudar este código @hugocsl, muito obrigado !! perfeito

Comment: O que significa o ::after

Comment: @Sora então MUITO resumidamente um ::after é um pseudo-elemento, são elemento construídos no CSS, eles não são tags html, o assunto é um pouco extenso, mas não é difícil de entender. Vou te indicar um artigo que vale a pena parar 15min pra dar uma olhada, vai ser mais didático do que eu tentar explicar aqui no comentário rss, da uma olha aqui que vai abrir sua cabeça https://www.devmedia.com.br/css-conheca-os-pseudo-elementos/38183

Comment: Vou ler, obrigado !!